# JQuery - what is the event for "cursor in textbox"?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, focus

I am trying to do something similar to what is used by Twitter for their signup page:

https://twitter.com/signup

I've seen it used before, where placing your cursor in the textbox / input field changes the text beside it. What is this event called? So I can use an "if 'cursor in textbook' then... " in my code. Is it the "focus" event? Or something else? Because I can't seem to get it to work.

And to take this a step further. Can I use Jquery to recognize the characters being typed within the textbox and define that as an event? i.e. password field needs 8 letters and at least one number and one special character. Can I use Jquery to recognize these characters within the field and generate the appropriate response? And if not, what's the best approach to doing that?

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a hover event as NiftyDude suggests, it's actually a focus event. Hovering over the field does nothing on the sign up page, putting your cursor into the field, aka focusing into the object causes the text to appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q87LE/ there's a nice example for you.